# C# encrypt and Crypto++ decrypt

Tags: c#, c++, encryption, aes, crypto++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

#include"modes.h"   
#include "aes.h"
#include "filters.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    //Key and IV setup
    //AES encryption uses a secret key of a variable length (128-bit, 196-bit or 256-   
    //bit). This key is secretly exchanged between two parties before communication   
    //begins. DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH= 16 bytes
    byte key[ CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH ] = {0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01};
    byte iv[ CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE ]={0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01};

    //Now is the time for all good men to come to the aide...";
    //std::string plaintext="{50602604|U800EDE73F241AC2E58A7D74C879D1D77|4DB6C4}";
    std::string ciphertext;
    std::string decryptedtext;

    //
    // Dump Plain Text
    //
    std::cout << "Plain Text (" << plaintext.size() << " bytes)" << std::endl;
    std::cout << plaintext;
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;

    //
    // Create Cipher Text
    //
    CryptoPP::AES::Encryption aesEncryption(key, CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH);
    CryptoPP::CBC_Mode_ExternalCipher::Encryption cbcEncryption( aesEncryption, iv );

    CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter stfEncryptor(cbcEncryption, new CryptoPP::StringSink( ciphertext ) );
    stfEncryptor.Put( reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>( plaintext.c_str() ), plaintext.length() + 1 );
    stfEncryptor.MessageEnd();

    //
    // Dump Cipher Text
    //
    std::cout << "Cipher Text (" << ciphertext.size() << " bytes)" << std::endl;

    for( int i = 0; i < ciphertext.size(); i++ ) {

        std::cout << "0x" << std::hex << (0xFF & static_cast<byte>(ciphertext[i])) << " ";
    }

    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;

    //
    // Decrypt
    //
    CryptoPP::AES::Decryption aesDecryption(key, CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH);
    CryptoPP::CBC_Mode_ExternalCipher::Decryption cbcDecryption( aesDecryption, iv );

    CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter stfDecryptor(cbcDecryption, new CryptoPP::StringSink( decryptedtext ) );
    stfDecryptor.Put( reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>( ciphertext.c_str() ), ciphertext.size() );
    stfDecryptor.MessageEnd();

    //
    // Dump Decrypted Text
    //
    std::cout << "Decrypted Text: " << std::endl;
    std::cout << decryptedtext;
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Please check revised C# code  at [Getting different output when using AES encryption in c# and online tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38875447/getting-different-output-when-using-aes-encryption-in-c-sharp-and-online-tool/38878258?noredirect=1#comment65123196_38878258).

Ideally I want to decrypt that encrypted output of c# using c++ (crypto++).
But while testing encryption and decryption in c++ i am not getting same output as c# in encryption itself.

Below is my SAMPLE CODE.
and my OUTPUT IS:

```
Plain Text (51 bytes)
{50602604|U800EDE73F241AC2E58A7D74C879D1D77|4DB6C4}
Cipher Text (64 bytes)
0x36 0xe7 0x78 0xf8 0xb8 0x97 0x15 0x6c 0xc3 0x73 0xea 0xa8 0x1b 0x12 0x71 0xc2 0xa0 0x5a 0xf2 0x40 0x60 0x89 0x6b 0x8 0x70 0x90 0xc9 0xb6 0x75 0x57 0xf7 0x22 0x73 0x3d 0x15 0xab 0xb1 0xd5 0xe5 0x73 0x85 0xe 0xa5 0x7e 0xa9 0xd2 0x7c 0xf2 0x87 0x83 0xac 0x79 0xc3 0x13 0xb7 0x89 0xfc 0x63 0x68 0x75 0x99 0x87 0x37 0xab
Decrypted Text:
{50602604|U800EDE73F241AC2E58A7D74C879D1D77|4DB6C4}
```

Comment: Kindly give some solution ...waiting for an answer. .thank you

Comment: The best I can tell, ***`Plain Text`*** is equal to ***`Decrypted Text`*** even though `std::string plaintext` is commented out in your C++ sample program. What is the problem with besides values magically appearing :)

Comment: Thanks for observing,But i forgot to re-comment it back.if i did commented my ouput wont able to come.please ignore that plain text."it is not commented"....."decrypted text" is doing well.problem is in "encrytped text"(cipher text)which is shown in output.